# How to Create and Access Session .net core api?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to create and access session in api. For example i have api called Login,Profile. When the login api is called at that time i need to create session and i need to access the session in profile api. When the session is cleared the login and profile api don't allow the user to access. How to do it.

Thank you..

Comment: APIs are stateless. They don't have sessions.

Comment: Thanksfor your response @Chris Pratt .Is there any other possible to maintain the session

Comment: No. There's no session to maintain. Each request is unique, and you must pass in all data necessary to service the request along with the request (via the request body and/or request headers). It's not clear what you're ultimately trying to achieve, so it's impossible to help you further than that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt how can we store small info between user of api? if no session exist in web api?

Comment: That's not how APIs work. The client is responsible for transmitting back any and all information the server needs. The server simply sends the info the client needs via the response. This then just becomes part of your documented API, i.e. the server returns X in the response body, you, as the client, need to send X back as part of your request.

Comment: More to the point, there is no "path" for an API user. A web user, for example, has to go to page X, submit a form, which then redirects them to page Y, where they take action Z. An API client can just request Z directly, and in fact, *should* request Z directly.

Comment: You can use an InMemory database like Redis or you can use Cache.

Comment: @ChrisPratt lets say i want to generate an unique Id when API recives a call, and the storage it on my HttpContext so i can access throw the entire logic through IHttpContextAccessor for logs. In this case should we use session or is there other thing we can use?

Answer (score 6):

Actually .net core can access session easily. Session mechanism is a basic feature in aspnet (.netcore as well)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I think you just need to add

```
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });
```

in `ConfigureServices` 
and:

```
app.UseSession();
```

in `Configure`

Then you can use it anywhere by injecting `ISession` where you need. As this is distributed by design you should serialize your data using something like `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and deserialize them back.

This feature described here has nothing with security concepts.

Comment: Injecting ISession ? Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

In Startup.cs you can add cookie authentication by adding this line (you can also specify options for length of session, etc).

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie();
```

To create a session on sign-in, from a controller, you can call this to sign in as a user with a set of claims (basically key/value pairs that describe what you need to know about the user):

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(userId, claims);
```

This creates a ClaimsPrincipal that can be accessed via the User property on Controller:

```
User.HasClaim("someclaim", "somevalue")
```

Ultimately the middleware encrypts the claims and saves them to a cookie, so the authentication is still stateless from the server's perspective. Be aware though that the encryption key it uses by default is tied to the machine so you'll have to use something like [azure or redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) if you plan on scaling to multiple server instances.

If you want to have a full login & user management system, the easiest way to go is probably ASP.net identity which provides the APIs for handling users, policies, access groups, and some of the tricky stuff like password storage using Entity Framework. For more info on that, check out this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

---

As a side-note, for more generic session state, [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2) has data about other session state options, but since you asked about logins, the best option is probably to use the authentication APIs.

Comment: does this also work for an API base project

Answer (score 1):

All right, there are two things you need to do. In **startup.cs**:

1- Add **app.UseSession();** to **Configure** method.

2- For more controlling on cookies insert following codes into **ConfigureServices** method:

```
options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
```

Like this if it solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core 5 - WebAPI,

1. Create a UserLoginSessionMiddleWare class.

```
    public class UserLoginSessionHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public UserLoginSessionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IJwtAuthentication jwtAuthentication)
        {
            var token = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
            var userType = jwtAuthentication.ValidateToken(token);
            if (userType != null)
            {
                httpContext.Items["CurrentUser"] = userType;
            }
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

2. Inside Invoke() method, access Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext object as parameter.
3. Create and assign the myObject that needed to store in session like,
   `httpContext.Items["SessionObject"] = myObject;`
4. Add UserLoginSessionHandlerMiddleware to request pipeline in Startup.cs -> Configure() method.
   `app.UseMiddleware<UserLoginSessionHandlerMiddleware>();`
5. Access the httpContext.Items["SessionObject"] from your ApiController class

Answer (score -1):

First install nuget package - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session

In Startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .....
    services.AddSession(options => {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);//You can set Time  
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
    .....
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ....
    app.UseSession();
    ....
}
```

In HomeController file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
      HttpContext.Session.SetString("key", "value"); // Set Session  
      var x = HttpContext.Session.GetString("key"); // Get Value of Session
    }    
}
```

You can also set integer value in session, use SetInt32 method and get from GetInt32 method. Hope it helps you..

Comment: The question pertains to Web API Controllers and NOT MVC Controllers.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is the solution you are looking for

in startup.cs

in Configure method add the below code

```
app.UseSession();
```

in ConfigureServices method add the below code

```
  services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(x=> 
    {
       x.Cookie.Name = "Cookie name";
       x.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); // idle time for the session                
    });
```

I creating the session in the class file example : UserLogin.cs

```
    private ISession session => httpContext.Session;
        public UserLogin(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            this.httpContext = httpContext;
        }
   private void SetSession(ClassInstance ObjOutput)
        {

            session.SetString("SessionID", ObjOutput.strSession.ToString()); 
        }
```

in the above code i have injected the HttpContext to class and strSession is the GUID which i will get it from SP,

To validate the session in the api, create the Action filter, In that filter you can get the session in the from context of the OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) method

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Session"]; this line will get the session from header
context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionID"); this line will get the current session
```

if it both matches it is okay if not

you can use the below code to tell session expired

```
string strExceptionOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new response()
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                    message = "Session Expired"
                });
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(strExceptionOutput);
```