# Session not working in ASP.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to use the session capability in ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET Core 3.1). As a test, I configured my project as follows.

0. Install NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session`.
1. Add service methods in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`.

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();
```

2. Use session in `Configure` in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();
    
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

3. Set a session variable in one of my routes in my controller.

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("currentUser", "value1");
```

However, I keep getting this error.

> {"type":"NullReferenceException","message":"Object reference not set
> to an instance of an object.","stackTrace":"   at
> Api.Routes.MainRoute.Handler(ILogger`1 logger) in MainRoute.cs:line
> 16\n   at Api.Controllers.MainController.MainRoute(String
> authorization) in MainController.cs:line 264"}

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please post your entire `Configure` method - because the order of invocation of `app.` methods is important.

Comment: **Please post the entire stack-trace** of the `NullReferenceException` - what makes you so sure it's related to Session-state?

Comment: `AddDistributedMemoryCache` <-- why are you using the **distributed** memory-cache when you haven't configured the distributed cache client? (e.g. Redis, memcached, etc). Instead, for single and smaller web-applications you probably want just `AddMemoryCache()`.

Comment: I've done what you said. I used `AddDistributedMemoryCache` because it resolved an error like `Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSessionStore'.`

Comment: Please read out the thread in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868207/how-to-create-and-access-session-net-core-api) regarding sessions in API. Hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: You may refer to the document I mentioned below. That worked for me

Answer (score 2):

> The order of middleware is important. Call UseSession after UseRouting
> and before MapRazorPages and MapDefaultControllerRoute .

[Session and state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-session-state)

Change your code to this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseSession();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-session-state) helped me to set session, and this is my startup file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```