# HttpContext.Session.GetString always returns Null in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, asp.net-core-webapi, session-state

I'm working in ASP.NET Core 6 and what I am trying to do is: set my list to session then get session info. But although there is no problem when setting it to session. When I try to get from session with `GetString`, it always returns null.

1. `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`:

[image]

2. `Configure` in `Startup.cs`:

[image]

3. `UserRepository.cs`:

[image]

4. Code block in the `UserService.cs` that I set session and then try to get:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as **properly formatted text** - do **NOT** post images of code ....

Comment: You can check the session id from when you are setting and getting and make sure it is same. if not same you might want to explain your flow for us to help.

Comment: I tested your code  but it works as normal. You can try to see if the session id is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to not using Sessions in `WebApi` projects. because its not very common.

Read [this](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to see how session works.

This why you always getting `null`, because you are not sending `SessionId` back to it, and he says `Oh a new User`  lets create a new session for him...

In a brief description, When you are using `Sessions`, your client should keep an id (called `SessionId`) and send it back to your API using `HttpHeader`s. this is done automatically when you have a `Web Application` and web browsers are aware of it, they keep this logic encapsulated so you can easily use it.

If you are forced to use sessions in `WebApi` read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868207/how-to-create-and-access-session-net-core-api) answer:

Note: good practice is to writing a middleware and using an AccessToken to work as a SessionId for you.